# Extremely slow when saving pixel values from images within a folder using os.walk()

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning

I am trying to create a file named `data.pickle` that contains pixels values of every images within a folder. The format of `data.pickle` is similar to mnist dataset, that is, a tuple of 2 numpy arrays.

First I test the code with only 1 folder that contains around 1000 jpg images (size of 15kb/image) and 1000 png images (size of 1.3kb/image). The code runs fine for the first execution, but if I delete the `data.pickle` file and run again the code will run much more slowly. I am new to python, I wonder if python keeps the data on the memory even after the execution? This is unreasonable.

Then, if I use the whole dataset I have (10 times bigger than the above), the code will be no longer executable (The execution get killed after 1 day of running)

Can you please indicate where am I doing wrong or suggest me some better method. I really appreciate your help.

Thank you and have a nice day.

Here is my code:

```
import os
import pickle #to save tuple
import cv2
import numpy as np

PATH_DATA = 'data'
#data folder structure:
#data
#    |
#    category1
#    |       |
#    |       input 
#    |       |   |
#    |       |   images0000001.jpg... #1000 images
#    |       |
#    |       ground_truth
#    |           |
#    |           gt0000001.png... #1000 images
#    category2... #10 categories

def add_slash(path_list): #add a slash between every path
    return '/'.join(path_list)

images = [] #list of train images
groundtruths = [] #list of train labels

for path_in_data, dirs_in_data, files_in_data in os.walk(PATH_DATA): #get category = dirs list
    for category in dirs_in_data: #loop through every category
        for path_in_category, dirs_in_category, files_in_category in os.walk(add_slash([path_in_data, category])): #get dirs in category
            for dir_ in dirs_in_category: #proceed into groundtruth folder
                if dir_ == 'groundtruth': #only process groundtruth folder
                    for path_in_groundtruth, dirs_in_groundtruth, files_in_groundtruth in os.walk(add_slash([path_in_category, dir_])):
                        #loop through each images
                        files_in_groundtruth.sort() #to ensure the data obtained is the same every execution
                        for file_ in files_in_groundtruth:
                            groundtruth = cv2.imread(add_slash([path_in_groundtruth, file_]))
                            foreground = cv2.imread(add_slash([path_in_groundtruth.replace('groundtruth', 'input'), file_.replace('gt','in').replace('png','jpg')]))
                            #append image and groundtruth to list
                            images.append(foreground)
                            groundtruths.append(groundtruth)
                        break #only process top directory in groundtruth
                else:
                    continue #skip input folder, only process groundtruth folder
            break #only process the top directory in category
    images = np.asarray(images) #convert list to numpy array
    groundtruths = np.asarray(groundtruths)

    #save as a tuple for use
    print(f'Saving dataset to {path_in_data}')
    with open(f'{path_in_data}/data.pickle', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump((images, groundtruths), f)
    break #only process the top directory in data
```

Comment: What are the dimensions (width x height) in pixels of your images? Are they currently colour or greyscale? If currently in colour, do they need to remain in colour? Maybe you could share a couple?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Hi, thank you for your consideration. The dimension is ```240x360x6``` (a concatenation of 2 images  of ```240x360x3```) . They do need to remain in color.

Comment: Assuming each pixel is 8-bit, each image will take 240x360x6 bytes, or 0.5MB of RAM. So 1,000 images will take 0.5GB and 10,000 images will need 5GB of RAM. That seems rather a lot. Can you open one image at a time and append to your pickle file maybe, then you only need 0.5MB of RAM. I completely understand that may not be possible or sensible for your use case.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It is actually the case because I merely have 7GB RAM PC. I am trying another approach. Thank you for your consideration :D